# Adapt shipping surcharge code

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Looking to adapt the following code, so currently this adds 1% to the basket if the country is US

I need £35 amount not a percentage and to only apply with Country UK and postcode BT* (all BT postcodes)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
  global $woocommerce;
  
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
 
    $county     = array('US');
    $percentage     = 0.01;
 
    if ( in_array( $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_country(), $county ) ) :
        $surcharge = ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total ) * $percentage;
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Surcharge', $surcharge, true, '' );
    endif;
  
}
```

Comment: This is a fairly simple change to the logic. What specifically don't you understand, or need help with?

Comment: WooCommerce and other 3rd party plugins are off topic and not in this stacks scope. You should ask via their official support routes or in their communities. As a side-note, where you directed here by their support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an untested modified version of your code:

```php
function woocommerce_bt_postcode_surcharge() {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_country() === 'GB' ) {
        $postcode = $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_postcode();
        if ( isset( $postcode )
             && strtoupper( substr( trim( $postcode ), 0, 2 ) ) === 'BT' ) {
            $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Surcharge', 35, true, '' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woocommerce_bt_postcode_surcharge' );
```

Note that

- I've copied your use of the $woocommerce global, but if I was writing this myself I'd use WC() instead
- I've also copied the true flag from the add_fee line, which means that the surcharge is taxable. Is that what you meant? See the [add_fee](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Cart.html#method_add_fee) documentation.
- and if I were a customer I'd probably appreciate a better explanation than just 'Surcharge', since this seems a rather large amount (but then I don't know what you're selling or why you're charging this)
- I also don't know how or when this event gets called. If it can get called multiple times for the same cart then you might need to

  - check whether or not the fee already existed before adding it again, although it's also possible that the cart itself will deduplicate fees
  - spot that you've added the fee but the customer has now changed their delivery address so that it's no longer BT, and remove the fee.

---

And here's a version extended to cover more postcodes:

```php
function woocommerce_bt_postcode_surcharge() {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_country() === 'GB' ) {
        $postcode = $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_postcode();
        if ( isset( $postcode ) ) {
            $prefix = strtolower( substr ( trim ( $postcode ), 0, 2 ) );
            // 35 surcharge for BT or IV
            if ( $prefix === 'BT' || $prefix === 'IV' ) {
                $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Surcharge', 35, true, '' );
            }
            // 50 surcharge for RG
            if ( $prefix === 'RG' ) {
                $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Surcharge', 50, true, '' );
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woocommerce_bt_postcode_surcharge' );
```

Comment: This worked a charm, thank you, yes we did adjust the name from Surcharge, can I ask another stupid questions, if I have multiple postcodes to apply this to is 'BT, AB, CD, EF' and so on

Comment: Hi, anyone know what I need to do to include more than one postcode

Comment: Thank you, I thought the same, but I seem to break it each time, as i'm using - strtoupper( substr( trim( $postcode ), 0, 2 ) ) === 'BT', 'IV' ) but this throws up errors

Comment: I've added a version where we have two postcodes where we charge 35 and another postcode where we charge a different amount 50.